# UI5: Floating Container that Moves as User Scrolls?

Tags: sapui5

Is there a control in which I can place, say, a button in so that the button stays in the view of the user as (s)he scrolls up or down the page?

This is similar to freezing a pane in Excel.

Comment: no, but it is relatively easy to make the button sticky using css.

Answer (score 0):

The `sap.m.Page` has an option to define a [floating footer](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.Page%23controlProperties)

This might be an option. see [demo](https://output.jsbin.com/goduwuqiba)